# Rebus Message Mutator

Tags: rebus

At one point Rebus supported Message Mutators. I can't seem to find them anymore in the Rebus source code. Were they renamed? Do they still exist?

Sample code:

```
Configure.With(senderAdapter)
    .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq(SenderInputQueueName, "error"))
    .Events(e =>
        {
            e.MessageMutators.Add(new EvilMutator("first"));
            e.MessageMutators.Add(new EvilMutator("second"));
            e.MessageMutators.Add(new EvilMutator("third"));
        })
    .CreateBus().Start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Rebus 2" (all versions of Rebus since 0.90.0) does not have message mutators, because it's super extensible, and adding something that mutates an incoming/outgoing message is pretty easy with the incoming/outgoing pipelines.

The pipelines follow the "Russian doll" model where each step is responsible for calling the rest of the pipeline.

Adding a new "mutator" step can be done like this – first, we create a step that is capable of mutating incoming/outgoing messages:

```cs
public class MyMutatorStep : IIncomingStep, IOutgoingStep
{
    public async Task Process(OutgoingStepContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        // here we have the message
        var message = context.Load<Message>();

        // mutate (or, more like "cripple", actually )
        context.Save(new Message(headers: message.Headers, body: new object()));

        await next();
    }

    public async Task Process(IncomingStepContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        // here we have the message again
        var message = context.Load<Message>();

        await next();
    }
}
```

and then we decorate the pipeline, injecting the step before serialization/after deserialization respectively:

```cs
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Options(o => o.Decorate<IPipeline>(c => {
        var pipeline = c.Get<IPipeline>();
        var step = new MyMutatorStep();

        return new PipelineStepInjector(pipeline)
            .OnReceive(step, PipelineStepRelativePosition.After, typeof(DeserializeIncomingMessageStep))
            .OnSend(step, PipelineStepRelativePosition.Before, typeof(SerializeOutgoingMessageStep));
    }))
    .Start();
```

In this example, I mutate the outgoing message by replacing the message body with `new object()`, which is probably not what you want  but hopefully, you can get an idea of the possibilities.

Comment: Oh man, this is awesome! I can’t wait to try this out. Thanks!